# Minify MySQL package for CRUD usage only

Tags: mysql, windows

I've downloaded mysql community edition (win32, zip) from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/),
which is 1.64GB in size (extracted).
While i've seen XAMPP or other ready-to-launch server bundles runs with mysql package less than 50mb in size.
So, how can I minify the huge mysql package under 50mb just for database usage only?

Note that, I only need mysql for basic database entries and just for development purpose in a portable environment (USB Drive)

Answer (score 0):

You have essentially download the complete server package, which includes clients, headers, samples, documentation, etc. etc.

For a minimal install, you need to download the web msi installer (from [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)), and then only choose the server component.

The msi installer is less than 2 MB and you need to select only the server component for a minimal install.

For more details, refer to the [installer manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-installer.html).

Comment: is it possible to do it with zip package, because i'm working in portable enviorenment